# When Using Azure SDK with apache guacamole extension getting application startup failure

Tags: guacamole, azure-identity

When adding the below dependency to extension/guacamole-auth-jdbc-base the application's startup fails with the error ClassNotFound for error. There must be some dependency conflict but not able to understand which dependency is causing the issue.

Have tried using azure-sdk-bom to remove azure dependency version but was of no effort.

Have also tried getting the mvn dependency tree but most of the library result in been conflict with/without the azure dependency mentioned. Please help to understand how the postgres jar is build

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>5.38.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.guacamole.auth.postgresql.PostgreSQLAuthenticationProvider

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the issue. The azure SDK was adding a transitive dependency in the guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgres module. Adding exclusion list for the azure sdk in childe module pom (guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgres) solved the issue.

```
<!-- Guacamole JDBC Authentication -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.guacamole</groupId>
            <artifactId>guacamole-auth-jdbc-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.guacamole.auth.postgresql.PostgreSQLAuthenticationProvider` indicates that the Java class `PostgreSQLAuthenticationProvider` from the package `org.apache.guacamole.auth.postgresql` cannot be found at runtime.

This could be due to several reasons:

1. `The guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgresql` module is not included in your build. This module contains the `PostgreSQLAuthenticationProvider` class. Make sure you have included this module in your build.
2. The `guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgresql` module is not correctly built. If you're building Guacamole from source, make sure the build completes successfully and the resulting `.jar` file is placed in the correct directory.
3. The `guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgresql` module is not on the classpath. When starting your application, make sure the `.jar` file is on the classpath.
4. There's a version mismatch between Guacamole and the `guacamole-auth-jdbc-postgresql` module. Make sure both are using compatible versions.

As for building the PostgreSQL JAR, you would typically do this by cloning the Guacamole client repository and building it using Maven. The resulting JAR file should be placed in the `GUACAMOLE_HOME/extensions` directory.